# Syntax error (1067230): Unknown filter 'Crypt'

Tags: errors, syntax, filter

I'm running into a strange problem: when running my LaTex code on 1 pc, I do not have any problem (running with TeXstudio).
When running exactly the same code on another pc, I get the error "Syntax Error (1067230): Unknown filter 'Crypt' "

I cannot find any information on this error. Anybody who knows more about this and how to solve?

Many thanks!

Comment: It's unlikely this will be enough information.  Could you trim the offending file down to a minimal working example that has those same symptoms?

Comment: It may be related to some kind of password protection on the pdf, either the pdf itself or some other pdf that is included in your document (with `\includegraphics` or `\includepdf`). See similar cases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023913/failed-to-create-default-crypt-filter-strange-ios-cgpdfdocument-wierdness and https://lwn.net/Articles/174448/. If you have Linux you could try running `pdfinfo` on the file, that may give more information.